# Terminal with advanced copy paste capabilites

Tags: terminal, software-rec, clipboard, terminal-emulator, kitty

Kitty terminal has a feature where one can run a python script that captures text via regex and allows copying directly to clipboard (see https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/kittens/hints/)

The matches are selected via some assigned letter, it's a very neat feature. I have a couple of hotkeys for capturing words, uuids, urls, etc so I never leave the keyboard.

Unfortunately, I hate that kitty forces one to set `$TERM` to `xterm-kitty` which opens a can of worms.

Is there another fast terminal emulator with the same functionality, without the `$TERM` shenanigans?

Comment: It's obviously doable in Emacs, but it may require a bit of code if you want _exactly_ the same selection interface rather than something broadly similar. Do you need the same kind of on-screen selection using numbers, or can it be a different mechanism? In xterm, I think it's only doable without on-screen selection (you have to decide “I want the 3rd URL” without an on-screen hint) or by opening another window for the selection. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' its acceptable as long as I don't have to touch the mouse. Emacs may be an idea, and although I use it once in a while, I'd prefer a regular terminal emulator